# Change order of the server list in Hyper V Manager

Tags: hyper-v

I'm using the Hyper V Manager on Windows 10 Pro and the list of servers on the left hand panel is in the order I added them. As I've only been adding them as they've come online or as I've needed them (someone else set them up) they are in the order 1 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 2 - 8 and I can't rearrange them.

I've tried dragging them but this does nothing. I could delete them all and re add them but that shouldn't be necessary, plus servers 3 and 4 aren't available yet and I'd need to do that again when they are.

Is it possible to rearrange the order of the server list in Hyper V Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation the server list is populated at start up and is always in alphabetical order. While this isn't the answer to my question as asked it does achieve what I wanted (servers in order 1 to 8)

The settings for the server list are stored in %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Client\1.0\virtmgmt.VMBrowser.config but no matter what order I saved in this file it is always overwritten by alphabetical order.